# Dumping data from one column to another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a refresh history table in a stored procedure. I have created a table where the first 4 columns will insert data from another table. When there is the next refresh, the first 4 columns data should move to the next 4 four columns and the first 4 columns will take data from the table for the current refresh.

However, when I do this process, it will just pick one row from the previous 4 columns and update the same information throughout. Not sure why it is not dumping first 4 column data to another 4 columns in same table. Each refresh can change the number of rows. Below is the sample and script used to run the process.

Created `#temp` table from another table with required data

```
Insert Into dbo.InitialTable (ID, Value, Active, Refreshdate)
    Select ID, Value, Active, Refreshdate
    From #temp

Select 
    ID, Value, Active, Refreshdate
into 
    #Previousday 
from 
    dbo.InitialTable


update dbo.InitialTable
Set ID1 = T.ID,
    Value1 = T.Value,
    Active1 = T.Active,
    [Refreshdate1] = T.[Refreshdate]
From #Previousday T
```

[image]

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: When you want to update a table based on values from another table, you need to set the relevant relationship between those tables (the table that is getting updated, and the table/s where the update values are coming from).  You have no relationships (ie. JOINs, I'm referring to) between the "InitialTable" and your "#PreviousDay" temporary table.  As a first step, try just setting up a SELECT statement that produces your "Expected Output", then you will essentially be 90% of the way there

Comment: Why are you using columns as a substitute for rows? When newer data is to be added, why not add it as new rows, instead of trying to shift the old data across into other columns?

Comment: Now i added as new row.